# How to find out number of mappers and reducers used for an oozie job?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie

I have a set of oozie jobs running in parallel, is there a way to find the the total number of mappers and reducers a particular oozie job has used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your`mapred-site.xml mapreduce.job.reduces and mapreduce.job.maps`property. if you are not seeing then default value for this property from mapred-default.xml will be used. you can set these properties if not found in mapred-site.xml

Comment: Does this property set value at each job level? Is there a way to find for an oozie job level..? Since my oozie-job triggers multiple map-reduce jobs.

Comment: Yes, you can specify in workflow.xml for each map-reduce action like `<property>
      <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>`